# Custom query for a subresource

Tags: eve

I have a subresource like `'X/:parent_id/Y?=where{'a':'b'}'`. This it gets transformed to a MongoDB query as `$and:[{'parent_id},{'a':'b'}]`.

Can I convert it to `$or:[{'parent_id},{'a':'b'}]`?

I have tried with a pre_GET operation and altering the lookup but the :parent_id value it is not populated yet in the lookup (if it ever does), and the database fetch hook is for after the data has been fetched, so is not a solution.

Really appreciated.